# Establishing Authorship

Tags: google-authorship

I went through all the steps of setting up authorship on my website, but it doesn't seem to be working. My photo appears in some search results, but not for my website. I attached a screen shot of search results which shows my website at the top (without photo thumbnail) and other results with the photo. [image: search results showing my website without photo, and other search results that include my photo]

How can I get it to show up with my website?

Comment: See this related question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65420/why-has-google-removed-authorship-images-from-its-serps?rq=1

Comment: As announced by John Mueller on [8/28/2014](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JohnMueller/posts/HZf3KDP1Dm8), Google will stop showing authorship results in Google Search, and will no longer be tracking data from content using `rel=author` markup. See [this](http://searchengineland.com/goodbye-google-authorship-201975) for more.